# & as sibling for mixin in LESS

Tags: css, less, mixins, dotless

I built a mixin to handle icon sprites in my solution, which basically loops through a list of class names and sets the background position relative to it's index in the sprite

```
@icon_size-small: 16;
@icon_size-medium: 24;
@icon_size-large: 32;

.commonIcons(@iconSize, @y: 1, @x: 0) {
    @posY: (@iconSize * @y);
    @posX: (@iconSize * @x);

    background: url('images/icons/commonIcons@{iconSize}x@{iconSize}.png') -@posX + 0px -@posY + 0px no-repeat;
    height: @iconSize + 0px;
    width: @iconSize + 0px;
}
```

I then call this mixin inside of another one like this

```
.icons_list-small(@modifier, @x) {
    .icon-clock             { .commonIcons(@icon_size-small, 1, @x); }
    .icon-checkmark         { .commonIcons(@icon_size-small, 2, @x); }
    .icon-stop              { .commonIcons(@icon_size-small, 3, @x); }
etc
```

and the whole thing is then actually used like this

```
.small-button {
    .icons_list-small(0);
}
```

So the background position is calculated based on which .icons_list-xxx I use, and the parameter I'm sending in in .small-button decides which y-index is shown (the sprite has 3 variants in a row).

This all works fine when generated as children inside of .small-button, but I've now run up against a case where I need the list generated as *sibling selectors* to .small-button (giving me .small-button.icon-clock { })

Implementing it like these examples gives me parse errors,  understandably:

```
.small-button.icons_list-small(0);
    or
.small-button {
    &.icons_list-small(0);
}
```

So the question: does anyone have a suggestion for what I can do in this instance?

Thanks for any help guys!

**Edit:** I found a fix myself, but if anyone has a more elegant solution I'd be happy to hear it!

What I did was extend the .icons_list-small mixin like this

```
.icons_list-small(@modifier, @x) {
    @{modifier}.icon -clock { .commonIcons(@icon_size-small, 1, @x); }
```

Which is then called like this

```
.icons_list-small(~".icon--inverted", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the `&` in your mixin:

```
.icons_list-small(@x) {
    &.icon-clock {
      .commonIcons(@icon_size-small, 1, @x);
    }
    &.icon-checkmark {
      .commonIcons(@icon_size-small, 2, @x);
    }
    &.icon-stop {
      .commonIcons(@icon_size-small, 3, @x);
    }
}
```

And when you want to obtain the previous behaviour, to use:

```
.small-button {
  & * {
    .icons_list-small(0);
  }
}
```

Which would generate

```
.small-button *.icon-clock {...}
...
```

that is equivalent (in CSS) to

```
.small-button .icon-clock {...}
...
```

And using it without the `& *`:

```
.small-button {
    .icons_list-small(0);
}
```

will generate:

```
.small-button.icon-clock {...}
...
```

Comment: Thanks Helder,
I updated my original question with a solution, but I think yours makes more sense as it's easier to read (ie, looks more like you would expect CSS/less to read).

Great idea, thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw., instead of `& *` or simply `*` (`&` is not necessary there) it could be something like `@{_}` (with `@_: ~" ";`). `*` will obviously burden browsers for no reason. Actually I would define two mixins for each case, like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/e8635be815c77a39177a#file-24059233-less).